automation of adding user to security group of identity management system through vba
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & userDN)
' Add the user to the group's member attribute
objGroup.PutEx 3, "member", Array(objUser.ADsPath)
objGroup.SetInfo

Getting the error of access denied with the line "objGroup.SetInfo".
I have written vba code to add the user. Group name is accessible, ldap is accessible, but getting the error of access although manually i am able to add the user in the security group. Group name and user names, i have put in the excel tab to pick automatically.
i try to add user automatically in the security group. Getting

run time error -2147024891 (80070005): Access is denied.

